# How to provide encrypted channel between locally hosted server and client?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, ssh

I'm creating an Android application that lets the device act as a server so that other clients on the same subnet can send/retrieve files from it (currently HTTP and SSH (via SCP command only) are supported).

A priority of mine is having the file transfer be encrypted.  The obvious solution is an HTTPS transfer, but my average user may be put off by the fact that their browser will show the connection as "not entirely secure" because I won't have a certificate for their locally-hosted server.

My second idea was to use SCP, which is inherently secure, from the browser, but I found out there's really no way to get a browser to open an SSH/SCP connection without some plugin, and I want my solution to require nothing but the app itself.

My third idea was to have a channel that is unsecure, but to encrypt the files end to end such that a file only touches the wire AFTER it has been encrypted.  I'd use pre-existing libraries in Java (for the Android server) and Javascript (for the web-based client).

But I feel that solution would be very slow for sending many small files, since instead of encrypting the stream, you have the overhead of encrypting each file entirely before sending.

To ensure that this question is specific enough for Stack Overflow:

How do I go about sending a file securely between a web browser-based client and a locally hosted server?

Comment: You _could_ experiment with setting up ssh tunnels to wrap your traffic, but I doubt you will find a satisfying solution. If I understand correct, then users are meant to use that service by browser only. In that case everything that does _not_ use https will be marked as insecure. And there is a good reason for that.

Comment: One question: if the service is only to be used on a private network, then why is encryption required? Is it the content of the files that is so sensitive or are you concerned about authentication credentials?